# File size statistics for file sharing sites

Tags: file, testing, statistics

I'm currently developing a file sharing platform and I would like to make my stress tests as realistic as possible. To do that I need to generate a lot of test files, and to do that in the most realistic manner, I need to know how the sizes of files uploaded to such a service are distributed.

The only thing I could find was [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dangl/2012/10/18/what-is-the-average-size-of-an-office-document/), which cover my needs to some extend but I would like some general statistics and not just data for certain document types.

If anyone has some data they are willing to share I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the average size of a song is different from the average size of an entire album, and different from a DVD movie and different from a 4k movie.